# iphone - Strang behavior when I set a UIImageView's frame while is in CGAffineTransformMakeScale animation

Tags: iphone, animation, uiimageview, transform, frame

I have a UIImageView showing an image with the contentMode of UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill.

Then I am associating a animation (about 30 seconds) of CGAffineTransformMakeScale with the UIImageView.

```
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,1);
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:30];
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.9,1.9);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

After 30 seconds, when a round of animation is done, I will set another image to the imageView and restart the animation.

Everything is fine. But when I try to rotate the UIImageView to adapt user's selection of device orientation, it becomes wired.

When the user is about to change the orientation, I set the UIImageView's frame to CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1004) or CGRectMake (0, 0, 1024, 748), accordingly.

The strange thing is:

if the frame of UIImageView is changed while the animation, it is fine. But when the next image comes and starts a new round of animation, the UIImageView suddenly became small in the center of screen (is supposed to be full screen) and then the animation of zoom-in started as usual, just not full screen any more.

Can anyone tell me how to control the frame or orientation while the UIImageView has a transform with it?

Because I guess this is where it went wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoth [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW5) for the `frame` property:

> **Warning:** If the transform property is not the identity transform, the value of this property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.

You should probably be messing with `center` and `bounds` instead, if you are using transformations.

Answer (score 1):

Frame property is not defined when transforming.  Use bounds instead of frame in this case.